# ubuntu 13.04 is there a way to make steremix same as windows?

Tags: sound, microphone

Hello guys i am searching if there a way to stream the computer sound to microphone, another microphone than the default one.

For example make people at Skype hear what i hear.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. You wish to record "what you hear"?

Comment: for example i want people on skype hear what i hear

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it on my system:

Install `pavucontrol` with `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`. Then start it with `pavucontrol` or find `PulseAudio Volume Control` in the menu.

Go to the `Input Devices` tab and on the bottom of it select `Show: All Input Devices` on the dropdown list.

Then click the tick with the tooltip `Set as fallback` next to the monitor output of your sound card. This should make this source as the default source and now Skype will use that input device to record. I'm not sure if Skype will register this while you are in call though.

[image: pavucontrol monitor output]